# Jackson ObjectMapper not able to parse string as hashmap

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I want to parse a Json String to Map<String, Object> and use the same in the existing application.

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

public class ObjectMapperDemo {

    public static String applicantJson = "{\\\"lead_id\\\":null,\\\"finder_number\\\":null,\\\"applicant_index\\\":0,\\\"applicant_id\\\":100314,\\\"loan_application_id\\\":3000312,\\\"person\\\":{\\\"lastName[PROTECTED],\\\"firstName\\\":\\\"Cathy\\\",\\\"maternalName[PROTECTED],\\\"middleName\\\":\\\"Kimberly\\\",\\\"dateOfBirth[PROTECTED],\\\"ssn[PROTECTED],\\\"itin[PROTECTED],\\\"last4Ssn[PROTECTED],\\\"last4Itin[PROTECTED],\\\"oktaId\\\":null,\\\"suffix\\\":\\\"Sr\\\",\\\"title\\\":null,\\\"clientId\\\":null,\\\"sipClientId\\\":null,\\\"customerId\\\":null,\\\"inUSSince\\\":null},\\\"email\\\":[{\\\"home\\\":\\\"SwNjh67784@oportun.com\\\"}],\\\"address[PROTECTED],\\\"street[PROTECTED],\\\"street[PROTECTED],\\\"city[PROTECTED],\\\"state\\\":\\\"FL\\\",\\\"postalCode\\\":\\\"33144\\\"}],\\\"identification[PROTECTED],\\\"number[PROTECTED],\\\"expirationDate\\\":\\\"2023-02-02T00:00:00.000Z\\\",\\\"dateOfBirth[PROTECTED],\\\"firstName\\\":\\\"Cathy\\\",\\\"middleName\\\":\\\"Kimberly\\\",\\\"lastName[PROTECTED],\\\"maternalName[PROTECTED],\\\"suffix\\\":\\\"Sr\\\",\\\"issuingCountry\\\":\\\"US\\\",\\\"issuingState\\\":\\\"CA\\\",\\\"issuingCity[PROTECTED],\\\"issueDate\\\":null,\\\"street[PROTECTED],\\\"street[PROTECTED],\\\"postalCode\\\":\\\"94063\\\",\\\"city[PROTECTED],\\\"state\\\":\\\"CA\\\",\\\"country\\\":null}],\\\"phones\\\":[{\\\"phoneNumber\\\":\\\"689-165-2363\\\",\\\"phoneType\\\":\\\"HM\\\"},{\\\"phoneNumber\\\":\\\"332-621-7769\\\",\\\"phoneType\\\":\\\"CL\\\"}]}";

    public static Map<String, Object> ConvertValueFromObject(Object obj) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        return objectMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Map<String, Object> testMap = ConvertValueFromObject(applicantJson);
        System.out.println(testMap.keySet());

    }

}
```

The stacktrace thrown is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{\"lead_id\":null,\"finder_number\":null,\"applicant_index\":0,\"applicant_id\":100314,\"loan_application_id\":3000312,\"person\":{\"lastName[PROTECTED],\"firstName\":\"Cathy\",\"maternalName[PROTECTED],\"middleName\":\"Kimberly\",\"dateOfBirth[PROTECTED],\"ssn[PROTECTED],\"itin[PROTECTED],\"last4Ssn[PROTECTED],\"last4Itin[PROTECTED],\"oktaId\":null,\"suffix\":\"Sr\",\"title\":null,\"clientId\":null,\"sipClientId\":null,\"customerId\":null,\"inUSSince\":null},\"email\":[{\"home\":\"SwNjh67784@oportun.com\"}],\"address[PROTECTED],\"street[PROTECTED],\"street[PROTECTED],\"city[PROTECTED],\"state\":\"FL\",\"postalCode\":\"33144\"}],\"identification[PROTECTED],\"number[PROTECTED],\"expirationDate\":\"2023-02-02T00:00:00.000Z\",\"dateOfBirth[PROTECTED],\"firstName\":\"Cathy\",\"middleName\":\"Kimberly\",\"lastName[PROTECTED],\"maternalName[PROTECTED],\"suffix\":\"Sr\",\"issuingCountry\":\"US\",\"issuingState\":\"CA\",\"issuingCity[PROTECTED],\"issueDate\":null,\"street[PROTECTED],\"street[PROTECTED],\"postalCode\":\"94063\",\"city[PROTECTED],\"state\":\"CA\",\"country\":null}],\"phones\":[{\"phoneNumber\":\"689-165-2363\",\"phoneType\":\"HM\"},{\"phoneNumber\":\"332-621-7769\",\"phoneType\":\"CL\"}]}')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4325)
    at ObjectMapperDemo.ConvertValueFromObject(ObjectMapperDemo.java:19)
    at ObjectMapperDemo.main(ObjectMapperDemo.java:25)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{\"lead_id\":null,\"finder_number\":null,\"applicant_index\":0,\"applicant_id\":100314,\"loan_application_id\":3000312,\"person\":{\"lastName[PROTECTED],\"firstName\":\"Cathy\",\"maternalName[PROTECTED],\"middleName\":\"Kimberly\",\"dateOfBirth[PROTECTED],\"ssn[PROTECTED],\"itin[PROTECTED],\"last4Ssn[PROTECTED],\"last4Itin[PROTECTED],\"oktaId\":null,\"suffix\":\"Sr\",\"title\":null,\"clientId\":null,\"sipClientId\":null,\"customerId\":null,\"inUSSince\":null},\"email\":[{\"home\":\"SwNjh67784@oportun.com\"}],\"address[PROTECTED],\"street[PROTECTED],\"street[PROTECTED],\"city[PROTECTED],\"state\":\"FL\",\"postalCode\":\"33144\"}],\"identification[PROTECTED],\"number[PROTECTED],\"expirationDate\":\"2023-02-02T00:00:00.000Z\",\"dateOfBirth[PROTECTED],\"firstName\":\"Cathy\",\"middleName\":\"Kimberly\",\"lastName[PROTECTED],\"maternalName[PROTECTED],\"suffix\":\"Sr\",\"issuingCountry\":\"US\",\"issuingState\":\"CA\",\"issuingCity[PROTECTED],\"issueDate\":null,\"street[PROTECTED],\"street[PROTECTED],\"postalCode\":\"94063\",\"city[PROTECTED],\"state\":\"CA\",\"country\":null}],\"phones\":[{\"phoneNumber\":\"689-165-2363\",\"phoneType\":\"HM\"},{\"phoneNumber\":\"332-621-7769\",\"phoneType\":\"CL\"}]}')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:311)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:444)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4389)
    ... 3 more
```

I even tried by passing the String as an Object

```
Map<String, Object> testMap = ConvertValueFromObject((Object) applicantJson);
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Why are the quotes double-escaped?

Comment: Use only single slash to escape double quotes like, `"{\"lead_id\":null,\"finder_number\":null}"`. Also the json data itself is valid, for example: `"person":{""lastName[PROTECTED],"firstName":"Cathy"`. Here key `""lastName[PROTECTED]` has 2 double quotes and there is no corresponding value for key `lastName[PROTECTED]` etc

Comment: In json we have double quotes, but when java changes the json to string it adds a backslash for each of the quote.

Comment: still the same error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @shmosel, the JSON is NOT valid, it was my bad to blindly believe the data sent through one of the reliable services to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the JSON submitted as input was invalid (even after removing the double slashes which Intellij Idea duly converts while copy pasting Json into java editor. Meanwhile the error messages from Jackson can be a bit meaningful and less misleading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).